# MySQL query combining several tables

Tags: python, mysql, database

### Background

In order to obtain data for my thesis I have to work with a large, fairly
complicated MySQL database, containing several tables and hundreds of GBs of
data. Unfortunately, I am new to SQL, and can't really figure out how to
extract the data that I need.

### Database

The database consists of several tables that I want to combine. Here are the
relevant parts of it:

```
> show tables;
+---------------------------+
| Tables_in_database        |
+---------------------------+
| Build                     |
| Build_has_ModuleRevisions |
| Configuration             |
| ModuleRevisions           |
| Modules                   |
| Product                   |
| TestCase                  |
| TestCaseResult            |
+---------------------------+
```

The tables are linked together in the following manner

```
Product ---(1:n)--> Configurations ---(1:n)--> Build

Build ---(1:n)--> Build_has_ModuleRevisions ---(n:1)--> ModuleRevision ---(n:1)--> Modules

Build ---(1:n)--> TestCaseResult ---(n:1)--> TestCase
```

The contents of the tables are

```
> describe Product;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


> describe Configuration;
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Product_id | int(11)      | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name       | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


> describe Build;
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field            | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id               | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Configuration_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| build_number     | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| build_id         | varchar(32)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| test_status      | varchar(255) | NO   |     |         |                |
| start_time       | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| end_time         | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+------------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


> describe Build_has_ModuleRevisions;
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field             | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id                | int(11)  | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Build_id          | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| ModuleRevision_id | int(11)  | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------------+----------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


> describe ModuleRevisions;
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Module_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| tag       | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
| revision  | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL |         |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


> describe Modules;
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name    | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
+---------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


> describe TestCase;
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field        | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id           | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| TestSuite_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| classname    | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| name         | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| testtype     | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+--------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+


> describe TestCaseResult;
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| Build_id    | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| TestCase_id | int(11)      | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| status      | varchar(255) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| start_time  | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
| end_time    | datetime     | YES  | MUL | NULL    |                |
+-------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

As you can see the tables are linked with `*_id` fields. E.g. `TestCaseResult`
is linked to a `Build` by the `Build_id field`, and to a `TestCase` by the
`TestCase_id` field.

### Problem Desciption

Now to my problem. Given a specific `Configuration.name` and `Product.name` as
input, I need to find all modules+revisions and failed testcases, for every
`Build`, sorted by `Build.start_time`.

### What I Have Tried

The following query gives me all the `Build`s given a `Configuration.name` of
`config1` and a `Product.name` of `product1`

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    `database`.`Build` AS b
        JOIN
    Configuration AS c ON c.id = b.Configuration_id
        JOIN
    Product as p ON p.id = c.Product_id
WHERE
    c.name = 'config1'
        AND p.name = 'product1'
ORDER BY b.start_time;
```

This doesn't even solve half of my problem, though. Now, for *every build* I
need to

1. Find *all* `Modules` linked to the `Build`

   - Extract the `Modules.name` field
   - Extract the `ModuleRevision.revision` field
2. Find *all* `TestCase`s linked to the `Build`

   - Where `TestCaseResult.status = 'failure'`
   - Extract the `TestCase.name` field linked to the `TestCaseResult`
3. Associate the `Build` with the extracted module name+revisions and testcase
   names
4. Present the data ordered by `Build.start_time` so that I can perform
   analyses on it.

In other words, of all the data available, I am only interested in linking the
fields `Modules.name`, `ModuleRevision.revision`, `TestCaseResult.status`, and
`TestCaseResult.name` to a particular `Build`, order this by `Build.start_time`
and then output this to a Python program I have written.

The end result should be something similar to

```
Build Build.start_time    Modules+Revisions               Failed tests
    1         20140301    [(mod1, rev1), (mod2... etc]    [test1, test2, ...]
    2         20140401    [(mod1, rev2), (mod2... etc]    [test1, test2, ...]
    3         20140402    [(mod3, rev1), (mod2... etc]    [test1, test2, ...]
    4         20140403    [(mod1, rev3), (mod2... etc]    [test1, test2, ...]
    5         20140505    [(mod5, rev2), (mod2... etc]    [test1, test2, ...]
```

### My question

Is there a good (and preferrably efficient) SQL query that can extract and
present the data that I need?

If not, I am totally okay with extracting one or several supersets/subsets of
the data in order to parse it with Python if necessary. But how do I extract
the desired data?

Comment: Incidentally, I suspect that the surrogate id column on `Build_has_ModuleRevisions` (and perhaps also `TestCaseResult`) is redundant. You appear to have a perfectly usable natural key here.

Comment: The guy who designed the database claims otherwise. :) Either way I cannot change the layout of the database, I just need to get data from it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like you'd need more than one query for this.  The problem is that the relationships of `Build <-> ModuleRevision` and `Build <- TestCaseResult` are basically independent.  `ModuleRevision`s and `TestCaseResult`s don't really have anything to do with each other as far as the schema is concerned.  You have to query for one and then the other.  You can't get them both in one query because because each row in your results basically represents one record of the "deepest" related table (in this case, either `ModuleRevision` or `TestCaseResult`) including any related information from its parent tables.  Therefore, I think you'd need something like the following:

```
SELECT
    M.name, MR.revision, B.id
FROM
    ModuleRevisions MR
INNER JOIN
    Modules M ON MR.Module_id = M.id
INNER JOIN
    Build_has_ModuleRevisions BHMR ON MR.id = BHMR.ModuleRevision_id
INNER JOIN
    Build B ON BHMR.Build_id = B.id
INNER JOIN
    Configuration C ON B.Configuration_id = C.id
INNER JOIN
    Product P ON C.Product_id = P.id
WHERE C.name = 'config1' AND P.name = 'product1'
ORDER BY B.start_time;

SELECT
    TCR.status, TC.name, B.id
FROM
    TestCaseResult TCR
INNER JOIN
    TestCase TC ON TCR.TestCase_id = TC.id
INNER JOIN
    Build B ON TCR.Build_id = B.id
INNER JOIN
    Configuration C ON B.Configuration_id = C.id
INNER JOIN
    Product P ON C.Product_id = P.id
WHERE C.name = 'config1' AND P.name = 'product1' and TCR.status = 'failure'
ORDER BY B.start_time;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer, I think I can work with the results of what your queries return. However, I need to select the B.id field in order to map the module+revision results to the testcase failures for each Build. I am also only interested in the test cases with status = "failure". I will edit your answer to reflect this, but feel free to change my edit if there is something in it you don't agree with.